# How to order dictionary when some of the values are the equal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to sort a dictionary containing scores `key` and values `names` and order them according to the highest score. When two people `names` have equal scores the dictionary cannot order itself correctly. How to fix this?

I'm a very rookie programmer. I've searched the web but could not find an answer yet.

```
def ranking_people():
    dictionary = {
        score_player_one : player_one,
        score_player_two : player_two,
        score_player_three : player_three
}
    sorted_dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(0), reverse = True )
    print("The ranking is: " + str(sorted_dictionary))
```

I expect the output to be:

> The ranking is: [(19, 'John 1'), [19, Alice 2], (16, 'Bob 3')]

The actual output is:

> The ranking is: [(19, 'John'), (16, 'Bob')]

Comment: if scores are equal you lose information in your dictionary. Create a dictionary with player names as keys, not scores

Comment: Or create score dictionary that have lists of names as values

Comment: I recommend that you work through a tutorial on lists and sorting.  You've chosen an inappropriate data representation, and your lack of familiarity with preferred techniques leaves you with too many problems to unravel at once.

Comment: @Prune Thank you for your comment. Where would you recommend I start/ what technique do you suggest I learn first to choose an appropriate data representation?

Comment: I suggest basic Python tutorials to get familiar with the language.  This will include basic data types and customary usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every key in dictionary has to be unique. If you do something like this:

```
my_dict[19] = 'John'
my_dict[19] = 'Alice'
```

John is overwritten by Alice. You may want to use names as keys and scores as values, but only if names are not repeated ('John 1' and 'John 2', not 'John' and 'John').

UPDATE:

Example solution of your problem using list of tuples, you can have duplicate names and scores:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def ranking_people():
    scores = [(10, 'John'), (8, 'Alice'), (8, 'Bob'), (14, 'John')]
    scores_sorted = sorted(scores, key=itemgetter(0))
    print(scores_sorted)
```